# Locust Swarm algorithm for path finding (devour and move on)

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, multithreading

I need to model a locust swarm that **devour** food stacks and **move on** to next stacks. I searched for articles and found few articles. These papers is about optimization applications but I want to convert it to a path finding algorithm to **reach multiple targets** (like randomly seeded many food stack). Swarm should split when food stack is not enough to feed them( multiple objective problem). How can I do this?

[image: Locust Swarm Algorithm]

x: position
v: velocity vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bspb9g9nTto) what you want?

As for finding the closest food stack, calculating the center of the swarm and using a simple A* algorithm to search all other food stack from the lowest minimum distance to the highest works, or even just a lookup table to map food stacks with their nearest neighbours (Only works if your food stacks are static and regrow).

### EDIT

To further answer the question:

The above solution might or might not work based on the new requirements stated in the comments. Or rather, it works, but becomes quite a heavy computation quite quickly.

You can assign N swarm members to stay at the food stack, and let the rest search for another stack. However, I would predict that the swarm members would spread out quite quickly, to the point where individual swarm members are searching for stacks. The Goal-Based Vector Field Pathfinding can handle that, but the A* might suffer.

If you want to take this aproach, you should really create a lookup table, or assign a array with the closest M stacks (Where M is some constant) to a field (so for each path-finding node in the world), which would use up a lot of memory.

Assigning swarm members to swarms might also help (Where every swarm gets a food stack assigned). This way the A* algorithm can operate on N members at once, as long as no member made it to the stack you can just make all members move in the same direction.

#### Best case

You can of course just create a vector field for every food stack with a weight, If you store the closest M stacks again. However, this would take up A LOT of memory (Multiple vector fields, so `struct { int dx; int dy; int weight }` ~= 12*M bytes PER NODE. This *REALLY* doesn't work for large world. If the world is small, this is the solution, but if the world is large, I think I can't help further.

Comment: Yes I want to that but I need to reach multiple targets. I forget to add "multiple targets"

Comment: @acs multiple targets at once? As in, split the swarm if a part of it is closer to another food stack? The above solution/video works perfectly for finding one food stack at a time.

Comment: Swarm should split if stack is not enough to feed them.

Comment: @acs I updated the answer

Comment: When you use the weighted vectors cant you just drop the nodes? the vector already provides you with a direction to the source and info for a pull(a factor of the weight(amount of food) and distance)

Comment: What about to use multiagent

Comment: @Neils: Think about a situation where there is a wall in between the swarm and the food stack...

Comment: Right, walls, I knew I was missing something. You might still be able to make it work by making your nodes larger or not gridbased but I guess you'll then end up creating a navmesh.